# Remove from ArrayList based on user input

Tags: java, arraylist

Building a very simple vehicle inventory for a basic programming course. It needs an add a new vehicle  method, list vehicle information method, remove a vehicle method and an update vehicle attributes method.

I've built an Automobile class with set and get methods:

```
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private int year;
    private int mileage;
    private int index;


    public Automobile(String make, String model, String color, int year,
                      int mileage, int index) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.index = index;
    }



    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) {
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

}
```

In my Vehicle class I now have an addVehicle method that looks like it'll work.

```
class Vehicle {
    static ArrayList<Automobile> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Add Vehicle to Inventory ##");
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle make: ");
        String make = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle model: ");
        String model = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle color: ");
        String color = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Vehicle mileage: ");
        int mileage = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int index = input.nextInt();
        
        Automobile newCar = new Automobile(make, model, color, year, mileage, index);
        
        vehicleList.add(newCar);
        
        System.out.println("Vehicle Added to Inventory Successfully");

    }
```

However, I'm stuck on the removeVehicle method that I'm trying to build:

```
    public void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int indexRemove = input.nextInt();

        if(    ){
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
        }

    }
```

I figure the easiest way to remove the vehicle is to ask for a user input vehicle index number and then remove that specific index number from the array. But I can't seem to make any progress and understand where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! I also displayed all vehicles in your list if you ever called your remove vehicle method.

**Solution 1**

I pretty much create a foreach loop that iterates over your existing list and checks if one exists by the index provided.  It then removes it in the if statement.  If it successfully removed it then it's true else false.

```
   public void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
        
        for(Automobile vehicle : vehicleList){
            System.out.println("make: " + vehicle.make  + "-" + "model: " + vehicle.model + "-" + 
                    "color: " + vehicle.color + "-" + "year: " +  vehicle.year + "-" + 
                    "mileage: " + vehicle.mileage + "-" + "index: " + vehicle.index);
        }
        
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int indexRemove = input.nextInt();
        
        Automobile automobileToBeRemoved = null;
        for(Automobile vehicle : vehicleList){
            if(vehicle.index == indexRemove){
                automobileToBeRemoved = vehicle;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(vehicleList.remove(automobileToBeRemoved)){
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
        }

    }
```

**Solution 2**

```
      public void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");

        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int indexRemove = input.nextInt();

        boolean removed = false;
        for (Automobile vehicle : vehicleList) {
            if (vehicle.index == indexRemove) {
                removed = vehicleList.remove(vehicle);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (removed) {
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
        }
```

**Solution 3**

```
        public void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");

        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        int indexRemove = input.nextInt();

        int originalSize = vehicleList.size();
        vehicleList = vehicleList.stream().filter(vehicle -> vehicle.index != indexRemove)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        if (vehicleList.size() != originalSize) {
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
        }
    }
```

**Solution 4**

```
        public void removeVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");

        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        try{
            int indexRemove = input.nextInt();
            int originalSize = vehicleList.size();
            vehicleList = vehicleList.stream().filter(vehicle -> vehicle.index != indexRemove)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

            if (vehicleList.size() != originalSize) {
                System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
        }
    }
```

**MISC export:**

```
        public void writeFile() {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
            for (Automobile vehicle : vehicleList) {
                fw.write("make: " + vehicle.make + "-" + "model: " + vehicle.model + "-" +
                        "color: " + vehicle.color + "-" + "year: " + vehicle.year + "-" +
                        "mileage: " + vehicle.mileage + "-" + "index: " + vehicle.index + "\n");
            }
            fw.close();
            System.out.println("File exported.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing file.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate you taking the time to provide multiple solutions. Could I easily implement a try/catch into the if/else statement on solution 2?

Comment: The only place I can see you implementing a try/catch is around the  "int indexRemove = input.nextInt();" in the event that someone feeds you a string instead of a number. I added it as solution 4.

Comment: Interesting. But in all reality, with my removeVehicle method, if anything other than an applicable index number is entered then it's going to give "No such vehicle exists" right?

I need a try/catch somewhere, so I'm thinking about including it in the printFile() method that I have to build. It needs to display a message asking if the user wants to print the information to a file (Y or N) and then print the file to a predefined location (e.g., C:\Temp\Autos.txt).

I'm not 100% sure what that would look like yet, but it feels like the right path. Thoughts?

Comment: You could do it on the print file if you want but I just updated solution 4 to displaying "No such vehicle exists" if they entered anything outside of an int.

Comment: I can wrap my head around solution 2, it's the one that makes most sense to me right now. The simplicity of an enhanced for loop is about where I'm at from a knowledge perspective. Where would you recommend starting on the print file? Your solution 3 prints the entire inventory but writing it to a file is a whole other story.

Comment: It depends on your criteria.  Is printing the file an option to the user like adding and removing a vehicle or do you have to print a new file every time you remove something from your list?

Comment: I think it's more about a hypothetical export of the inventory by printing to a predefined file location. So I would prompt the user to press 1 to add a vehicle, 2 to remove, 3 to update, 4 to print the inventory, and 5 to exit. Which means I'd create a method to print the information in the main class I'd imagine

Comment: What you're asking for now is out of scope of your post.  If you found my answer most helpful, please upvote it. 

HOWEVER, I updated my original answer with a write method.  Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeVehicle() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
    System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
    int indexRemove = input.nextInt();

    int oldSize = vehicleList.size();

    for (Automobile vehicle : vehicleList) {
        if (auto.getIndex() == indexRemove) {
            vehicleList.remove(vehicle);
            System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (vehicleList.size() == oldSize) {
        System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using listIterator, as it will help you traversing over the list, and will help you removing the element from the list as well

```
public static void removeVehicle() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
    System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");        
    int indexRemove = input.nextInt();
    ListIterator<Automobile> listIterator = vehicleList.listIterator();
    boolean removed = false;
    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        if(listIterator.next().getIndex()==indexRemove) {
            listIterator.remove();
            removed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(removed) {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to use the ListIterator for the "update the vehicle" piece of the inventory. I need it to update the vehicle, print the return value and then call the listing method and print the information to the screen. I think I'm close but am so unfamiliar with the this functionality.

Comment: `public static <AutoMobile> void updateVehicle() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
        System.out.print("Enter the make of Automobile: ");
        String make = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the model of Automobile: ");
        String model = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
        ListIterator<AutoMobile> iterator =(ListIterator<AutoMobile>) vehicleList.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 8, `Collection` (and therefore `List`) has method [`removeIf (Predicate p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which allows to remove all elements satisfying the given predicate applied to each element of the collection, so method and returns `true` if any element has been removed:

```java
public void removeVehicle() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("## Remove Vehicle from Inventory ##");
    System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");
    int indexRemove = input.nextInt();

    if (vehicleList.removeIf(car -> indexRemove == car.getIndex())) {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Removed Successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you requested for updateVehicle method, you can use below code,
but with this, I suggest you to override toString() method, even better if you override hashcode and equals method

```
public static void updateVehicle() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("## Upadate Vehicle by index number ##");
    System.out.print("Enter the Vehicle Index Number: ");        
    int indexRemove = input.nextInt();
    ListIterator<Automobile> listIterator = vehicleList.listIterator();
    boolean updated = false;
    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        Automobile mobile = listIterator.next(); 
        if(mobile.getIndex()==indexRemove) {
            
            System.out.println("Existing details : "+mobile.toString());
            
            System.out.print("Enter Vehicle make: ");
            String make = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Vehicle model: ");
            String model = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Vehicle color: ");
            String color = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Vehicle year: ");
            int year = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Vehicle mileage: ");
            int mileage = input.nextInt();
            
            mobile.setMake(make);
            mobile.setModel(model);
            mobile.setModel(model);
            mobile.setColor(color);
            mobile.setYear(year);
            mobile.setMileage(mileage);
            
            
            updated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(updated) {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Updated Successfully");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No Such Vehicle Exists");
    }
}
```